# How to insert or update or delete a record easy at once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE `pledge` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `category` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `amount` DOUBLE NULL, NOT NULL,
  `p_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

I added a unique key for user, location and category as index2.

I want to

```
INSERT a new record, if amount is not zero
UPDATE an existing record, if key (column user, location, category) exists
DELETE a record, if key (column user, location, category) exists AND amount is now zero



try {
  $conec = new Connection();
  $con = $conec->Open();
  $p_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `pledge`(
    `user`,
    `location`,
    `category`,
    `amount`,
    `p_created`)
    VALUES (
    :user,
    :location,
    :category,
    :amount,
    :p_created)";

  $pre = $con->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
  if ($pre->execute(array(
    ':user' => $user,
    ':location' => $location,
    ':category' => $category,
    ':amount' => $amount,
    ':p_created' => $p_created,
  ))) {
//      echo "Successful";
    }
  } catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
} // try
```

I found that I can use something like "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3='alpha';", but don't know how in above php code.
Since this exist, there might be also a possibility to delete instead of update if the amount is zero.

**Update:**

Thank you robbie for your hints. Somehow, I still make mistakes. I tried many ways, but ...

First I had to change the table. I dropped the primary key ID and added a new primary key containing the columns user, location, category.

To simplify my original question I updated only one column, but its actually two columns.

With that changes I was able to insert/update as I intended on the command line (Workbench):
INSERT INTO `pledge`(`user`, `location`, `category`, `mypercent`, `mybalance`,  `p_created`)
    VALUES ('5cdae45bdb5c5', 'Linz', 'A14', 50, 300, '2019-05-21 11:12:22')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `mypercent`=20, `mybalance` = 53;

Works as expected. First time it will be inserted with mypercent=50 and mybalance=300 and the second time I try the exact same command, I get the record updated to mypercent=20 and mybalance=53

However, I cannot get THIS syntax into my PHP program. This is the latest try:

```
try {

    $conec = new Connection();
    $con = $conec->Open();

    $p_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `pledge`(
            `user`,
            `location`,
            `category`,
            `mypercent`,
            `mybalance`,
            `p_created`)
            VALUES (
            :user,
            :location,
            :category,
            :mypercent,
            :mybalance,
            :p_created)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (`mypercent` = $percent[0], `mybalance` = $balance[0])
            ";
// worked on command line: UPDATE `pledge` SET `mypercent`='10',`mybalance`='10' WHERE `user`='5ce3770041037' and `location`='Linz' and`category`='A14';
// ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `p_mypercent`=20, `mybalance` = 53;

    $pre = $con->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    if ($pre->execute(array(
       ':user' => $user,
       ':location' => $locationid,
       ':category' => $category,
       ':mypercent' => $percent[0],
       ':mybalance' => $balance[0],
       ':p_created' => $p_created,
    ))) {
//      echo "Successful";
    } // if ($pre->execute(array(
   } catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} // try
```

This gives me a syntax error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(`mypercent` = 10, `mybalance` = 10) `mypercent`, ' at line 17

Comment: It's probably simplest to use PHP to read the amount from the table, if it doesn't exist, insert, if it does and the update would make it zero, delete, otherwise update.

Comment: What is your question actually? How to use ON DUPLICATE with PDO or how to use conditionals in PHP (like if ($amount > 0) insert/update else delete)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, each with Pros and Cons

1) The simplest, as Nick said is comments is two write three queries. Don't do this - if you have multiple calls at the same time then another user may try to update the same record in between the read and write.

1b) If you insisted on doing this approach, you could do using transactions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html  However there are risks with transactions that you need to handle, and it's a bit overkill for this operation.

2) The second simplest (and one I'd do) is to do an "ON DUPLICATE KEY" as you suggest in the question, and then a second operation to "delete if zero". This way, even if two events overlap, they will actually prevent each other from deleting the record, or both update the same record.

Critical note 1 : you need an UNIQUE index on `user` for this to work. Or drop "id" as a field, and use "user" as your primary key.

Critical note 2 : What you're missing is doing the maths in the SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `pledge`(`user`, `location`, `category`, `amount`, `p_created`)
    VALUES (:user, :location, :category, :amount, :p_created)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `amount`=`amount`-VALUES(amount)";
```

which says insert the amount if it does not exist, otherwise, do the match and update the record.

Then a separate query

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `pledge` WHERE `user`=:user AND `amount`=0";
```

(The "user=0" is not needed, but as you have user indexed, you don't have an index on "amount", it'll be faster. You could just clean up with `$sql = "DELETE FROM`pledge`WHERE`amount`=0";)`

3) The fanciest way of doing this is to user a trigger inside the database. You can tell the SQL server that "if amount is zero, then delete". Or mix it all in a stored procedure, but they are both also overkill.

Comment: I am fighting to implement the first part and get an error: Syntax error near ' )' at line 17 - This makes no sense to me at all, since the code is in the php script around line 122. I did write my example simplified, it is actually not amount but ($my_percent * $my_balance). The minus in front of VALUES I do  not understand.

Comment: Can you update with your sql that is throwing errors? The second VALUES says use the value of the column that would be inserted, taken from the first VALUES. If you need now maths at this point, you may need more than one reference to VALUES, or you do the maths outside in the param array. I can't answer that without seeing what you are doing..